# Strong inductive proof for this inequality using the Fibonacci sequence.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, fibonacci-numbers

**Problem**

I need to determine for what natural numbers is $2n < F_n$, where $F_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number determined by $F_0 = 0$, $F_1 = 1$ and $F_n = F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$.  I then need to prove my findings through strong induction.

**What I found**

I found that the inequality is true for all $n >= 8$.

**My attempt at proving by induction**

Basis: $2(8) < F_8$ = TRUE

Assume: $2(k) < F_k$

Show: $2(k) < F_k$ implies $2(k+1) < F_{k+1}$

$2(k+1) = 2k + 2 < F_k + F_{k-1} = F_{k+1}$

Thus

$2(k+1) < F_{k+1}$

Logic:

$2k < F_k$ by induction hypothesis

$2 < F_{k-1}$ because $F_{k-1}$ is at least $13$ when $k>=8$

$F_{k+1}$ is $F_k + F_{k-1}$.

**Is my proof correct?  Is this considered strong induction?**

Comment: You should have $F_k + F_{k - 1} = F_{k + 1}$, not $<$ right below your "Show" line. Otherwise, this looks correct.

Comment: Thanks.  But is this considered strong induction?

Comment: @Adriano How would I prove this with strong induction?  Will you leave an answer with example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, strong induction is when the induction depends on
more than just the preceding value.
In this case, 
you use the hypothesis for $k$ but 
not for any earlier values.
Instead, you use a much weaker result
($F_{k-1} > 2$) for the earlier value.

So, I would not call this strong induction.

If you use the hypothesis
($F_n > 2n$) for $both$
$k$ and $k-1$,
 the induction works because
$F_k > 2k$ and $F_{k-1} > 2(k-1)$
together imply
$F_{k+1} = F_k+F_{k-1}
> 2k + 2(k-1)
= 4k-2
> 2(k+1)
$
when
$k \ge 3$.

Note that the induction step works when
$k \ge 3$
but the induction hypothesis
is true only when
$k \ge 8$.
So the first case where you can
do the induction is
$k = 9$,
because you use the truth for
$k=8$ and $k=9$ to prove it for
$k=10$.

I would call this moderate induction,
since it depends on 
the previous two cases being true.

Comment: Wouldn't the induction step also work when $k=2$ (even though the induction hypothesis doesn't work for $k<8$)?

Comment: Thank you very much!  I feel like I am learning this!

Comment: What is needed is $4k-2>2(k+1)$ and this not true for $k=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is great. Here's how you would explicitly use strong induction. Note that you have already proved the base case for when $n=8$.

**Induction Hypothesis:** Assume that $F_n>2n$ holds true for all $n\in\{8,...,k\}$, where $k\ge8$.

It remains to prove the inequality true for $n=k+1$. Observe that:
$$ \begin{align*}
F_{k+1} &= F_k + F_{k-1} \\
&> 2k + 2(k-1) & \text{by the induction hypothesis} \\
&\ge 2k + 2(8-1) & \text{since } k \ge8 \\
&= 2k+14 \\
&> 2k+2 \\
&= 2(k+1) \\
\end{align*} $$
as desired. This completes the induction.

Comment: Thank you for posting this.

Comment: @positiveimpact No problem. =]

Answer (score 0):

We will change the indexing slightly to make it look like archetypal strong induction.

We show that if the result holds for all $i$ such that $8\le i \lt k$ then it holds at $k$.

Because it holds at for all such $i$, it holds in particular at $k-1$. Now argue as you did (with minor index shift) that since $F_{k-1} \gt 2(k-1)$ and $2\lt F_{k-2}$, we have $2k=2(k-1)+2\lt F_{k-1}+F_{k-2}=F_k$.

Of course we have not used the full strength of the induction hypothesis, but we have written out things in strong induction style.

Answer (score 0):

$F_n > 2n$ if $n > 8$.

*Proof:*

Consider $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$

Thus,

$$F_{n+1} = F_n + F_{n-1}$$

The idea is to show:

$$F_{n+1} > 2n + 2$$

By strong induction, for $n > 8$ since $P(8)$ is true,

$$F_n > 2n$$

$$F_{n-1} > 2n + 2$$

$$F_{n+1} = F_{n} + F_{n-1} > 4n + 2$$

*Lemma:* $4n + 2 > 2n + 2$

*Proof:*

$$4n + 2 > 2n + 2$$

$$4n > 2n$$

$$4 > 2$$

Hence,

$$F_{n+1} > 2n + 2$$